# How to mask part of signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, python, noise, gaussian, deep-learning

I am trying to implement masking in 1D signal data,
I saw in one paper that they are masking 70% of the signal as in the figure below:

[image]

In another study, they have mentioned that the mask part is replaced by a weak Gaussian noise.
[image]

How to do this kind of masking? Is there any sample python code?

Comment: The answer to your question **as stated** is to just set sections of the data to zero.  But doing so randomly will be useless or worse.  I believe that your question is "how should I mask _my data_ so that it is more useful", or even "how can my algorithm ignore parts of my data in a useful way?"  If you want answers that are going to help you solve your problem you need to _edit your question_ to give more detail about what you're measuring, why there's troublesome data in your measurements, what you want out of the data, and how the troublesome bits are distinct from the good bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Based on the image you provided, the signal's value is zero in certain specified intervals.

Here is the Python code to implement this task:

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a signal
signal = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10, 100))

# Mask the signal
masked_signal = deepcopy(signal)
masked_signal[:15] = 0
masked_signal[75:] = 0

# Plot the signal
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(signal)
plt.title('Original signal')

# Plot the masked signal
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(masked_signal)
plt.title('Masked signal')

plt.show()
```

[image]